# Autocmd treat user defined command differently?

Tags: autocmd

This works fine:

```
augroup au_test | au!
  autocmd BufNew * if 1 | echom 123 | endif
augroup end
```

But this doesn't work:

```
com Test echom 123
augroup au_test | au!
  autocmd BufNew * if 1 | Test | endif
augroup end
```

It results in following error when i create new buffer:

```
E488: Trailing characters:  Test | endif
```

Why ?

This behavior was found by [Samuel Jackson](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/26206/samuel-jackson) in this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/saving-a-scratch-buffer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vimscript (well, Ex) is weird in that each command will determine whether they'll take `|` as an argument or whether they'll allow it as a separator.

In the case of user-defined commands, they default to taking `|` as an argument, but you can override that by passing a `-bar` argument to the `:command` definition.

So, defining `Test` this way would have prevented the issue:

```
com -bar Test echom 123
```

See [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) for more details and a list of commands that take `|` as an argument:

> These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be followed by another Vim command:
>
> - `:argdo`
> - `:autocmd`
> - ...
> - a user defined command without the `-bar` argument
>
> To be able to use another command anyway, use the `:execute` command.

See also [`:help :command`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand), in particular the part that covers [`-bar`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bar).