# Concatenate vim command after :terminal

Tags: vimscript, terminal-buffer

Is there any way I can concatenate a command *after* `:terminal`?

For example `:terminal | <some_other_vim_command>` will pass `| <some_other_vim_command>` to the terminal that just opened, but how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: use `:exe ":terminal" | another_vim_command`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I've been looking for a duplicate but can't find one... We do have some questions on [:command missing -bar](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22318/18609) but we don't seem to have one on needing :exe for bar. Also, Vim help :| has a list of commands needing :exe but :term is not on that list and probably should be... If you'd like to take care of these that would be awesome, otherwise I'll take a closer look at them tomorrow. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is missing from Vims `:h :bar`. Will post a doc patch later.

Answer (score 4):

Not all Ex commands allow `|` to be used as a command separator, some Ex commands want to take `|` as an argument.

The common workaround is to use `:execute` to wrap those commands that do not allow `|` as a command separator.

See [`:help :bar` or `:help :|`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) for more details and a list of commands that take `|` as an argument:

> These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be followed by another Vim command:
>
> - `:argdo`
> - `:autocmd`
> - ...
> - `:normal`
> - ...
> - `:windo`
> - `:write !`
> - `:[range]!`

Most Ex commands (such as `:!`) that take a shell command as an argument will not allow `|` as a command separator, since shell commands typically use `|` as a pipe between shell commands, so they'll pass the `|` literally to the shell.

Note that `:terminal` is not on that list (as of Vim 8.2.598) but that's just an omission in the documentation and [@ChristianBrabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) offered to push a documentation patch to fix that in Vim.

The documentation in `:help :|` also mentions:

> To be able to use another command anyway, use the `:execute` command.
>
> Example (append the output of "ls" and jump to the first line):
>
> ```
> :execute 'r !ls' | '[
> ```

And [`:help :execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) also mentions that type of usage:

> `:execute` can be used to append a command to commands that don't accept a `|`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> :execute '!ls' | echo "theend"
> ```

In your particular case, you can use:

```
:exe "terminal" | <some_other_vim_command>
```