# Chaining user-defined commands

Tags: command-line, user-commands

Assuming I have defined 2 commands in `.vimrc`

```
MultipleEmptyLinesToOne
RemoveExcessiveSpaces
```

I can run them in command-line mode:

```
:exec "'<,'>MultipleEmptyLinesToOne" | exec "'<,'>RemoveExcessiveSpaces"
```

However this method doesn't support auto-completion while typing the commands.

I know that I can create a new user-defined command that runs them in a sequence:

```
command! -range RemoveExcessiveSpaces2 exec "'<,'>MultipleEmptyLinesToOne" | exec "'<,'>RemoveExcessiveSpaces"
```

but it would be still great to know whether I can type (chain) any user-defined commands in command-line mode and have auto-completion at the same time.

Comment: What I would do here is to enter in Ex mode (with `Q`), type the first command, `<ENTER>`, then the second, `<ENTER>` again, and then get out with `visual`. That way, you'll have autocompletion for the 2 commands

Comment: I'm not aware of a builtin to chain them with ranges, but using `-bar` will let you chain them with `|`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autocmd treat user defined command differently?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/autocmd-treat-user-defined-command-differently). I believe the same solution should work in your case.

Comment: @Zorzi gQ is even nicer imo

Comment: Another answer to this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144568/how-do-i-write-a-command-in-vim-to-run-multiple-commands